# Send post request with Angular 2 and Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, java, spring, angular, spring-boot

I use Angular 2 and Spring Boot. From an html form I want to send data to a local mongo db. The form has a Submit Function which should send the data to the PersonController Java file. But the post request does not work. 
I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

onSubmit() Function

```
    private serverUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/saveUser';

onSubmit() {

    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    this.http.post(this.serverUrl,
        {firstName: 'name.firstname',lastName: 'name.lastname'},
        {headers:headers})
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());

    this.name = {
        firstname: '',
        lastname: ''
    }
```

HTML Code:

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #nameForm="ngForm" >
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Firstname">Firstname</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname"
    required
    [(ngModel)]="name.firstname" name="firstname">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Lastname">Lastname</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname"
    [(ngModel)]="name.lastname" name="lastname">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

PersonController

```
@Autowired
PersonRepository personRepository;

@RequestMapping("/saveUser")
public String personForm(){
    Person person1 = new Person("Hans", "Meiser");
    personRepository.save(person1);
    return "saved";
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Are you getting errors/exceptions? What kind of debugging have you done? Doesn't work is hardly enough to help you out.

Comment: I have a general problem of understanding. First of all the angular 2 http.post function still does not send the post request to the spring boot server. In addition to that i am still not able to fetch the form data via angular 2 to save the data in a mongodb. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

sa, in your spring code your `@RequestMapping("/saveUser")` is bydefault mapped as `GET`. so you still add one property as given bellow.

can you pass method property in this mapping and can check it.

> @RequestMapping(value="/saveUser" , method=RequestMethod.POST

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the request type. also you have to set how you will recieve these input data. if you are sending them as a request body then you have to recieve them as the following as you are casting the input data to person to be saved directly.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveUser", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String personForm(@RequestBody Person person){
    personRepository.save(person);
    return "saved";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Spring request is a GET one and you are trying to call a POST method from angular. And in angular you need to subscribe in order for the http call to be fired.

Change to `@PostMapping('/users')`
When creating CRUD operation is a good naming practice to have the method type and the name is the name of the domain on plural.

> Spring

```
@PostMapping('/users')
public Person saveUser(@RequestBody Person person) {
 return personRepository.save(person);
}
```

> Angular

```
private baseUrl= 'http://localhost:8080';
```

```
const user = {firstName: this.name.firstname, lastName: this.name.lastname};
this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/user}`, user).subscribe(value => this.user = user);
```